# Keep external script from loading a URL

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I have a plugin for my website that adds a Disqus comment box to my articles. The plugin loads the Disqus script that adds the comment box, but it unfortunately also calls some URLs associated with ad tracking.

How do I prevent these URLs from being loaded?

Edit: I can't give code. The Disqus files are very large.

Comment: Posting the code part you mentioned would be helpful.

Comment: lol forgot that part.

Comment: Ask disqus about it.

Comment: @Sammitch Why would they help me? They want their tracking data.

Comment: Yep. So either they remove it, likely only if you actually pay for their service, or you work to remove it yourself thus violating their ToS and getting your account shut down. Or don't use Disqus. Pick your poison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot do that. If you want to add Disqus to your site then you have to concede to the fact that they will add their tracking data (why do you think they are providing this service for free).

Note: Currently, our large clients are really resenting the fact that they used Disqus for commenting, since they are now paying $99/month in order to hide the scammy ads that Disqus displays + it always adds its own tracking data.